# I got blank data after apply spread operator on createSelector result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reselect

I try to get updated data from createselector.

```
export const getFinalData = createSelector( getFirst ,
   (first) => {
     let subFirst = {...first.subfirst}
     let updatedData = subFirst.value * 10
     subFirst .subfirst =updatedData
     return subFirst ;
})
```

but in

```
let subFirst = {...first.subfirst}
```

I got blank data. I don;t know what's wrong

Comment: Can you show what `first.subfirst` is please?

Comment: Could you add the `getFirst` definition and the input data to the question? When `getFirst = array => array[0]` and the input data is `[{subfirst: {a: 1, value: 2}}]` the provided code works fine.

Comment: Kindly also add the exact error returned. Thanks.

Comment: First:{ subfirst:{parent:{ child1{...},child2:{subChild1:{xxxx},subChild2:{xxxxx}  }  }}}